# Получение данных с карты или скрипта

Tags: xml, веб-программирование, google-maps-api, http, карты

Как получить данные о точках продаж с сайта http://agence.orange.fr/fr/ile-de-france/paris для дальнейшего отображения их на карте?
Нужно получить такую же карту как на сайте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите внимательно в консоль, там есть запрос к такому url http://agence.orange.fr/point_of_sales.json. Если по нему перейти, то все станет на свои места.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку! А как вы это нашли?

Comment: в любом современном браузере нажимаете F12 и внимательно смотрите на вкладке networks.